# Incomplete pattern matches on this expression

Tags: f#

I receive a warning for the following code:

```
    | _ -> let card1::card2::remainingDeck = newDeck
           Some(card1, card2), remainingDeck
```

> Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value
>   '[_]' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).

Here's the rest of the code:

```
let newDeck = [for suit in suits do
                for face in faces do
                    yield {Face=face; Suit=suit}]

let deal = function
    | card1::card2::remaining -> Some(card1, card2), remaining
    | _ -> let card1::card2::remainingDeck = newDeck
           Some(card1, card2), remainingDeck
```

I have noticed that after several minutes of my editor being idle, when I build my solution again, the warning goes away.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the warning because the only information the compiler has about `newDeck` is its type. It has no information about length of the list - and if `newDeck` doesn't have at least 2 elements, `let card1::card2::remainingDeck = newDeck` will throw `MatchFailureException`.

Actually

```
let card1::card2::remainingDeck = newDeck
Some(card1, card2), remainingDeck
```

is equivalent to

```
match newDeck with
| card1::card2::remainingDeck -> Some(card1, card2), remainingDeck
```

The compiled MSIL is exactly the same.

Comment: That's a nice explanation! Better than what I could come up with!

Comment: I'm confused. Why would the wildcard code cause an exception? I thought I was binding a new deck to a list and then yielding a tuple for a hand and then the remainder of the new deck?

Comment: @sepp2k The first match is on the function parameter. If the parameter is less than 2 elements long, the 2nd (implicit) match is on `newDeck`. They are two different lists.